# GDAL gdal_polygonize.py TypeError

Tags: python, gdal

I am using GDAL to convert a .tif to .shp file.

```
gdal_polygonize.py input.tif -f “ESRI Shapefile” out.shp
```

However this does not work and results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/gdal_polygonize.py", line 166, in <module>
    drv = ogr.GetDriverByName(format)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.11/Python/2.7/site-packages/osgeo/ogr.py", line 5255, in GetDriverByName
    return _ogr.GetDriverByName(*args)
TypeError: in method 'GetDriverByName', argument 1 of type 'char const *
```

I don't believe there is anything wrong with the .tif file or the command

Comment: Are you still having this problem? I ask this because you asked [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193335/tiff-to-shapefile-using-gdal-slow-speed) a few minutes later which suggests that you got the `gdal_polygonize.py` tool working :)

Comment: I wondered if someone would notice! Two different computers ;) I can't get it functioning on a more powerful computer.

Comment: Are you using the same python version on both computers? Does the Python version match the version that GDAL was compiled/packaged for?

Answer (score 1):

If this is Python 3, I have just come across this problem, and it seems to be that gdal cannot handle unicode strings as input arguments.

It's a bit messy, but try

```
drv = ogr.GetDriverByName(str(format))
```

I am currently looking for a better solution.