# tiff to shapefile using GDAL - slow speed

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, python, gdal

I am converting a 500MB .tif file to .shp file using GDAL.

I am using the following:

```
gdal_polygonize.py .tiff file -f “ESRI Shapefile” out.shp
```

However, I abandoned the first attempt as in 12hrs it has 2% progress.

I split the `.tif` file into 20 pieces and the first chunk took 5hrs.

Is there a more efficient means of doing this conversion?

The ultimate aim is to convert `.tif` to `GeoJSON`. I am very familiar with the `.shp` to `.json` conversion and I am thus using `.tif` to `.shp` as a stepping stone.

The file in question is vegetation data from http://rmgsc.cr.usgs.gov/outgoing/ecosystems/Africadata/

The file in question - `af_labeled_ecosys.zip`

The intention is display the vegetation data.

Comment: What is your GeoTIFF like? What do you want out of it? gdal_polygonize is a pretty simple connected-pixel digitizer, so if your image has thousands of levels it will try to create many vector entities.

Comment: Having looked at the file, that's a 108,000 × 87,600 px data set of *all* of Africa. Are you sure you need all of it?

Comment: Good point! gdal_warp to reduce and all is well

Answer (score 1):

`Warp` to reduce the resolution. Went from `674MB` to `36MB`.

```
gdal_warp
```